# PKZ 1023 Battery

Tags: batteries, discharge

Does anyone happen to know the manufacturer's specs for the PKZ-1023 model battery?
All I know right now, is that is that it is NI-MH, 9.6V, and 1000mAh.

I was hoping to find a chart of discharge rates, maximum current output, etc.
Either I am being really thick with the stuff I *do* know, or I am looking in all the wrong places for the battery specs.

**update:**
Thanks for all the help EE.SE, I think I got what I needed! :) 
I would upvote both, but I don't have enough reputation apparently.

Comment: ParkZone is the manufacturer, judging from [this](http://www.horizonhobby.com/products/PKZ1023#t2).  If you contact them, they may be kind enough to provide you with the specs.  Another option is to mirror this question of yours at a dedicated RC forum.  May be you'll get lucky and somebody has profiled the battery.  Finally, don't forget this:  No datasheet => No sale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know who makes the cells in that pack, but they are a 2/3A NiMH probably similar to MAXX1000/MPIH1000A, KAN1050 or [GP1100](http://www.gpina.com/pdf/GP110AFHR_DS.pdf). Here are some graphs showing discharge characteristics:-

[image: MPIH1000 vs others] 
http://www.elektromodellflug.de/oldpage/akku-test/Gp100-Kan1050.htm
[image: GP1100 discharge test]
[image: KAN1050 discharge at 1, 2, 3 5, 10A]

Answer (score 1):

The pack seems to be made, or at least sold by, ParkZone (brand name of Horizon Hobby) for use in their RC airplanes.  (PKZ in model number = ParkZone?)  Their website only specifies NiMH 9.6V 1000mAh.

Judging from the voltage and photo the pack has 8 cells connected in series.  Unclear whether it has any protection circuitry in the pack, and as the connector has only 2 pins it probably doesn't have a thermistor (temperature sensor) to tell the charger if/when it gets too hot during charging.

http://www.parkzone.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=PKZ1023

As the capacity is 1000mAh, and it's intended for use in a high-drain application, a reasonable assumption would be that it's good for at least a 1C rate of discharge, so up to 1A sustained output current and possibly more than that in short bursts, say up to 2-3A.

Pragmatically speaking, you may be able to drain it faster than that if you need to, up to as much as 3-4A sustained, but the number of charge/discharge cycles could go down very dramatically with sustained use at higher current.  For any battery which isn't deliberately designed to be run at very high drain rates, the expected load is something like a 5 or 10 hour discharge (or less), so 1000/10=100mA to 1000/5=200mA.

It's unlikely that Horizon Hobby is the manufacturer of the cells, and probably not the assembled pack either.  If you wanted detailed data you'd need to find out which brand(s) of cells they use and get the data sheet from that manufacturer, if one is available.